# Expand ARG/ENV in CMD dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and I am taking in a LAMBDA_NAME from a jenkins pipeline.

I am passing in something like this: source-producer

And I want to call the handler of this function, which is named handler in the code.

This code does not work

```
ARG LAMBDA_NAME
ENV LAMBDA_HANDLER="${LAMBDA_NAME}.handler"
RUN echo "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"
CMD [ "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}" ]
```

The result of the run echo step gives back "sourceproducer.handler", which is correct.

The code above produces this error
[ERROR] Runtime.MalformedHandlerName: Bad handler '${LAMBDA_HANDLER}': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

But, when this same value is hardcoded, it works fine and executes the lambda function.

```
ARG LAMBDA_NAME
ENV LAMBDA_HANDLER="${LAMBDA_NAME}.handler"
RUN echo "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"
CMD [ "sourceproducer.handler" ]
```

How can I correctly use LAMBDA_HANDLER inside of CMD so that the top code block executes the same as the one below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the *shell form* of the CMD statement. With the *exec form* of the statement, as you have now, there's no shell to replace environment variable.

Use

```
CMD "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"
```

instead.

This is equivalent to this, using the *exec form*, which you can also use, if you prefer the exec form

```
CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}" ]
```

Comment: Thanks Hans! It does answer the question so have accepted this as the args seem expanded. However, I do get this error at runtime with both possibilities that you posted.

**entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument**