# Using argument in CMD for a Dockerfile(entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument)

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

I previously asked this question and got a solution to expanding arguments in a dockerfile.

[Expand ARG/ENV in CMD dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778018/expand-arg-env-in-cmd-dockerfile/73778047#73778047)

I think with AWS Lambdas the handler name has to be the first argument. I have a parameterized jenkins pipeline that takes in a parameter named LAMBDA_NAME and I append the handler to it.

When I hard-code the lambda name, there are no issues.

```
ARG LAMBDA_NAME
ENV LAMBDA_HANDLER="${LAMBDA_NAME}.handler"
RUN echo "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"
CMD [ "sourceproducer.handler" ]
```

But what I am looking to do is to use the LAMBDA_HANDLER variable above. When echo is called it correctly spits out "sourceproducer.handler"

At first, I tried to run it in exec form and ran into this issue
([ERROR] Runtime.MalformedHandlerName: Bad handler '${LAMBDA_HANDLER}': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

```
ARG LAMBDA_NAME
ENV LAMBDA_HANDLER="${LAMBDA_NAME}.handler"
RUN echo "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"
CMD [ "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}" ]
```

The question answered above, said to use exec form instead, so I tried both of these ways of running it

```
CMD "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}"

And 

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}" ]
```

However, now because I am using exec form "/bin/sh" is the first argument and it doesn't conform with AWS Lambda wanting the handler as the first argument.

I thought perhaps switching the order of the arguments would help, but it didn't.

```
CMD ["${LAMBDA_HANDLER}", "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
```

So, the question is how do I pass in LAMBDA_HANDLER argument AND have it be the first argument? Use entrypoint or custom shell script? Open to ideas about the approach

Comment: If you're allowed to have a script as the handler, then you might create a short script with a fixed name that runs the `${LAMBDA_HANDLER}`. Then you'd have the script name in the CMD and it'd be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I'm hitting 2 issues with that approach so far though

1) Cannot use CMD from shell script, not sure what the equivalent would be. I tried python3 sourceproducer, but ran into problems.

**RUN if [ "${LAMBDA_HANDLER}" =  "sourceproducer.handler" ] ; then \
       CMD do something; \**

2) The .sh default script is quite limited. It isn't recognizing commands such as docker or jq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up solving this doing something similar to what Hans Kilian suggested. Hardcoded a lambda name, and had that call the specific handler that I required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this answer when suffering from the same issue, but came to a possibly simpler solution.
As I could not provide the handler through `CMD` I simply overrode the `ENTRYPOINT` - this is perhaps not ideal, but having looked at the contents of the `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` I don't see any concerning impact

The `/lambda-entrypoint.sh` provided in the image looks like this

```bash
sh-4.2# cat /lambda-entrypoint.sh 

#!/bin/sh
# Copyright 2020 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "entrypoint requires the handler name to be the first argument" 1>&2
  exit 142
fi
export _HANDLER="$1"

RUNTIME_ENTRYPOINT=/var/runtime/bootstrap
if [ -z "${AWS_LAMBDA_RUNTIME_API}" ]; then
  exec /usr/local/bin/aws-lambda-rie $RUNTIME_ENTRYPOINT
else
  exec $RUNTIME_ENTRYPOINT
fi
```

So I override the `ENTRYPOINT` in my final stage as follows

```
FROM runtime
ARG FUNCTION_HANDLER
ENV FUNCTION_HANDLER=${FUNCTION_HANDLER}
COPY --from=publish ./app/out .
ENTRYPOINT /lambda-entrypoint.sh ${FUNCTION_HANDLER}
```

The `ARG` sets the stage to use the build arg provided. The `ENV` then sets the value in the runtime environment.  The `ENTRYPOINT` then overrides the default entrypoint passing the handler name.